# How to implement a user creating a file via form and then downloading it in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, paperclip, translation

I am building an online translation platform. When a job is done being translated and saved, I want the user to be able to download the translated version as a text file. It is currently saved in a string in the model called "target_text".

I know in ruby I can use this method:

```
File.open("translation.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write("my translated string") }
```

I am assuming I could tack the location for the file to be saved in front of the "translation.txt", but I am not sure what folder within my app I should specify?

Furthermore I want this file to be attached to the "job" object in the same way that paperclip can attach files, the difference being it's initiated server side. How should I go about this?

I have googled all over looking for an answer to this, and I want to make sure I do it in the cleanest way possible. I would really appreciate even directions to a good place to look to understand this concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand the question, but I hope this could help...

Instead of using

```
File.open("translation.txt", 'w') {|f| f.write("my translated string") }
```

try using the following

```
Tempfile.open(['translation', '.txt'], Rails.root.join('tmp')) do |file|

# this will create a temp file in RAILS_ROOT/tmp/ folder
# you can replace the 'translation' text part to any auto generated text for example
# Tempfile.open([@user.id.to_s, '_translation.txt'] will create
# RAILS_ROOT/tmp/1_translation.1fe2ed.txt
# the 1fe2ed is generated by Tempfile to avoid conflicting

  begin
    file << "my translated string"
    # this creates the file
    # add all the processing you need here... cause the next ensure block
    # will close and delete this temp file... so that the tmp dir doesn't get big.
    # you can for example add the file to paperclip attachment

    @user.translation = file
    # assuming that user has paperclip attachment called translation
  ensure
    # close and delete file
    file.close
    file.unlink
  end
end
```

also check the [Tempfile docs](http://apidock.com/ruby/Tempfile)... this is the practice i've been using... not sure if it's the best or not.. but it didn't create any issues so far
(even with paperclip s3 storage)